# Error when Android Studio see my Iphone connected on debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

For some reason I get this error, whenever Android Studio detect my phone connected, so I try to run it in Debug mode.
No application found for TargetPlatform.ios.
Is your project missing an ios/Runner/Info.plist?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
Any help please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, all you need to do is, open your Xcode, then navigate to Xcode >> Preferences >> Accounts. Ensure you are logged in with your Apple ID.

Next, navigate to Runner, click on it, NOTE: Ensure you have your Device selected right beside it Runner Button. [image: screenshot 1]

Then click Edit Scheme, when it loads, Set Run, Test and Profile's Build Configuration Options to "Profile".

Build Configuration:
[image: screenshot 2]

Then close.

Lastly, ensure you have your bundle identifier set to `com.yourdomainOrName.appname`, and your Team is also selected for the Signing.

If done correctly, your App should be up and running when you click build.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `flutter create .` from a terminal in your folder to re-create any missing files, as suggested in the message?

Comment: I have tried by running flutter create, but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: If you create a brand new project using `flutter create`, does that fail in the same way?

Comment: Yes it does: No option specified for the output directory, and gives me many options